# Maven - How to create a POM that place files in the root

Tags: maven, build, jar, pom.xml

I need to create a pom.xml file that builds a jar with certain files place on its root. The pom.xml I have now creates 3 directories BOOT-INF, META-INF and org. Below is the build section. I want the files to be at the same level as the directories (BOOT-INF, META-INF, org).

[sparc-jar.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yc19.jpg)

```
<plugins>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>oerg.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1.0</version>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build-info</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>

    </plugins>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.sh</include>
                <include>**/*.id</include>
                <include>**/*.yaml</include>
                <include>**/*.json</include>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
                <include>**/*.jar</include>
                <include>**/*.js</include>
                <include>**/*.map</include>
                <include>**/*.html</include>
                <include>**/*.hbs</include>
                <include>**/*.cer</include>
                <include>**/*.p12</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>

        <resource>
            <directory>.</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.yaml</include>
                <include>**/*.json</include>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
                <include>**/*.cer</include>
                <include>**/*.p12</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Comment: Put all the information you need into `src/main/resources` directory and remove all that configuration because it's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me... Configure the spring-boot-maven-plugin as follows:

```
<configuration>
   <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}</outputDirectory>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you nardos for the tip. However I still need the BOOT-INF and META-INF folders on the jar. Your configuration has removed them.